# ASP.NET GridView SelectedRow

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I my code fill data grid view with data and then I want to get back value of selected row like this

```
string pName = GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
```

unfortunately pName becomes empty string and I do not know why. Here is a example of code I am trying to work with.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new     DataColumn("Id"), new DataColumn("Jmeno") });
            dt.Rows.Add("John Hammond", "Canada");
            dt.Rows.Add("Rick Stewards", "United States");
            dt.Rows.Add("Huang He", "China");
            dt.Rows.Add("Mudassar Khan", "India");
            GridView2.DataSource = dt;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
    }

protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pName = GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
        Label1.Text = pName;
    }

<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
     OnSelectedIndexChanged = "OnSelectedIndexChanged"
    AutoGenerateSelectButton="True">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="ID" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Jmeno" HeaderText="Jmeno" />

                <asp:ButtonField Text="Click" CommandName="Select" ItemStyle-Width="30"  />
            </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

Both autogenerated select and Click does triger OnSelectedIndexChanged but I am not able to get any value from Cell[index]. Any ideas how to do so?

Comment: You must set AutoGenerateColumns="true". In addition, there is nothing in  Cells[0]. Try setting Cells[1] or Cells[2].

Comment: Actually it works! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by Arun Banik

> You must set AutoGenerateColumns="true". In addition, there is nothing in Cells[0]. Try setting Cells[1] or Cells[2]. –
>   Arun Banik

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `OnSelectedIndexChanged` function with below code. Since your select button is there in the 0th index position
`string pName = GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;` this line of code will fetch what is there in 0th index i.e. `SelectButton`,so pName will always be empty string.

```
   protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string pName = GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
      string Jmeno = GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
      Label1.Text = "<b>pName :</b> " + ID + " <b>Jmeno :</b> " + Jmeno;
    }
```